# What's the meaning of this "cast negative number to unsigned integer" idiom?

Tags: c#, casting, long-integer, unsigned, idioms

I am studying some code, and the Visual Studio compiler complained about a compilation error: casting a negative number to unsigned long integer.

However, that's how it is in the original source code, just like this:

```
var foo = new FancyMapArea((long)((ulong)-2147483648), (long)((ulong)-2147483648), 256, 256)
```

What could be the intent of this? And if it's silly, what I should do to compile this while still getting the intended results?

UPDATE / IMPORTANT NOTE:

This source code was generated by ILSpy decompiler, so perhaps it was not actually typed by a human developer.

Comment: This seems not to make sense. Since ulong has the same bytes as long. So skip the `(ulong)` cast.

Comment: Maybe it's using the cast as a method to get an absolute value.

Comment: May be a 2s-complement binary thing going on here.

Comment: Seriously what answer do you expect, why some external program do something, which can not be compile. My suggestion is because there is a bug in the program !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ulong` is not supposed to store signed integral values. Because it does not use the last bit for storing sign value of your integer. You have to use `unchecked` keyword to use something like this which will get you a wrap around behavior for the value

```
            string a = aaa.ToString();
            ulong b = ulong.MaxValue;   //18446744073709551615

            unchecked
            {
                b = (ulong)(-20);  //18446744073709551596
            }
```

All being said, if you are eventually converting to `long` then remove the intermediate conversion to `ulong` altogether.

```
var foo = new FancyMapArea((long)(-2147483648), (long)(-2147483648), 256, 256)
```

Comment: This is interesting since a "wrap around behavior" makes sense for the application (a mapping one, where coordinates are expected to "wrap" when you cross the 180° meridian, for example). So why do you think the original source didn't have the "unchecked" block?

Comment: Imagine if you have to check for overflow for each arithmetic operation? That would put a lot of performance penalty on the application. In most cases this is might not be required and you would like to know if you any possible overlapping in the code.

Comment: I mean, why the original source didn't have the "unchecked", since the way it is now it doesn't even compile! Either I need to put the "unchecked" (and modify the code - not desireable), or I need to do the same magic the original developer did, if any, so that the code compiles.

Comment: it seems this was requested for ILSpy to have unchecked/checked blocks. Please see [this link](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/commit/942131b06d30f80e16a71ed379510abe9ea055f6) And also discussion [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/issues/85)